# React unit test using vitest and react testing library mock method and api

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, axios, react-testing-library, vitest

Hi everyone i am new in react and unit test. I am trying to implement unit test in react using vitest and react testing library. I just confused how to unit test async axios api call.

so basically i have axios api called submit api

```
export const submitapi = (obj) =>
  axios.put("submit", obj);
```

which is called through component hooks useSubmit.js

```
export const useSubmit = () => {
 
 const callSave = ({ fields, setError }) => {
   submitapi(fields)
     .then((res) => {
       if (res.data.isError) {
        //show error message

         return;
       } else {
         //success message
       

         //navigate home;
       }
     })
     .catch((e) => {
        //show error message
     });
 };

 const onSubmit = ({ fields, setError, getValues }) => {
   // it has some validation
   
       callSave({ fields, setError });
   
  };
 return { onSubmit };
};
```

so far for unit test i have mock api for submitapi

```
 export const submitapi = () =>
  vi.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    data: {
      responseData: 
        {
          isError:false
        },
      
    },
  });
```

and unit test with vitest

```
   const mod = await vi.importActual("react-router-dom");
   return {
     ...mod,
     useParams: () => ({
       asbId: "1",
     }),
   };
 });
 

 
 vi.mock('~/api/submitapi');
 const {
   result: {
     current: { ContextProvider },
   },
 } = renderHook(() => useProviders());
 
 describe("myForm", () => {    

   afterEach(() => {
     cleanup();
   });
 
   
 
   test("should call submit", async () => {
       
       render(
       <ContextProvider>
         <MyForm  />
       </ContextProvider>,
       { wrapper: BrowserRouter },
     );
  
    
      userEvent.click(screen.getByText("Submit"));
    
     await waitFor(()=>{
       expect(submitapi).toHaveBeenCalledWith(testData);
     })
    
   
 });
```

so far i am getting error  [Function submitapi] is not a spy or a call to a spy!

Thank you in advance.